# Hibernate merge parent and update Lazy Child Collection List

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having a problem when I perform merge parent table, the existing child records will be insert rather than update.

For example, Member(Parent) and Address(Child) tables,

```
    public class Member implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "member", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<Address> addressList;
}


public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int address_id;

    @Column(name = "member_id")
    private int mem_id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    public Member member;
}
```

While I perform changes and merge(Member), the address record is being inserted rather than update the existing record.

Does anyone know what would be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

when you perform changes do you set correct address_id ? . Do some debugging and find address_id match with existing id in Address table.

in my approach class will look like below. I don't see  need of member_id attribute. because it is same as id attribute of member.

public class Address implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int address_id;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "member_id",  nullable = false)
public Member member;

public void setMember(Member member) {
    this.member = member;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, ya, I check the address_id and mem_id in address records, its exactly the same with my existing records. However, it would not update but insert a new records with new address_id

Comment: do you set member in Address object. addressObj.setMember(memberObj)

Comment: I didn't set it, but when debugging, I can see the addres.member is pointing to the original member. I do put my member object in spring @SessionAttributes, would it possible be the reason?

Comment: This is just some example fields of my tables, 
BTW, the Member can have multiple address, thus it cannot join directly from adress_id to member_id

Comment: of course member have multiple addresses , also every address has a member. .I'm stating set that member.So here join column is member_id. address_id is not used in joining at all.

Comment: But you mentioned don't see need of member_id attribute, without defining the column do we able to join it?

Comment: yes of course . in table level you have column called member_id. But that doesn't mean that you need separate member_id attribute in Address class. In entity class level just think  as a parent child relation , and this is the use of ORM

Comment: Means that I do not need to create member_id in Address class?
But if in this way, can I create a new Address entity and add to member?

Comment: Hi, I tried, but it still inserting new child records instead of update them.

Comment: Ok now you understands that we don't need separate member_id in Address . normally we use Set<Address> data structure instead of List<Address> try that and with fetch = FetchType.EAGER

Comment: The reason I use list because I will bind it to the spring form and update selected fields.
For lazy type, its because some members are allowed to have no address

Comment: having no address doesn't have a problem with fetch type. fetch type lazy means child members do not load at same time parents load.

Comment: If you fetch by eager, member without address will not be list out.

Comment: I don't it is correct. if no address for a particular member object it will have size zero address list.

Comment: If you using fetch.EAGER, the sql run as "join", thus for member do not have address will not result in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any **parent child relationship** in your snapshot code.

Please amend the code for child class with below code to create the inheritance relationship.

```
public class Child extends Member implements Serializable{
```

Extending the Child class to the Parent(Member) will reflect the required changes related to lazy loading.